# How can I take direct data form Ardruino server and upload to PC another ( installed SQL )

Tags: c#, winforms

I wrote 2 winforms as follows

1. Check the connection of the Ardruino to PC 1 and write the received information to log.txt file
2. Read selected information in log files and send them to PC 2 (SQL installed)

Note: PC 1 has 2 network cards (network card 1 receives the signals of the Arduino over the range: 192.168.1.2; Network card 2 connects to PC 2 via the range: 110.110.1.2)

How do I get the information I need from PC 1 and transfer them to PC 2 (with SQL installed) with only 1 program
My code Winform received form Arduino:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TCPIPSeverMutilClient
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int MAX_CONNECTION = 30;
        const int PORT_NUMBER =1989;
        int currentconnect = 0;
        delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

        static TcpListener listener;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(IPText.Text);

            listener = new TcpListener(address, PORT_NUMBER);
            AddMsg("Creat Sever with IP :"+ IPText.Text);
            AddMsg("Waiting for connection...");
            button1.Hide();
            listener.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTION; i++)
            {
               // new Thread(DoWork).Start();
                Thread aThread = new Thread(DoWork);
                aThread.IsBackground = true; //<-- Set the thread to work in background
                aThread.Start();
            }
        }

        private  void DoWork()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Socket soc = listener.AcceptSocket();
                currentconnect = currentconnect + 1;
                SetText("Numbers Connection " + currentconnect.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Connection received from: {0}", soc.RemoteEndPoint);
                try
                {
                    var stream = new NetworkStream(soc);
                    var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                    var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
                    writer.AutoFlush = true;

                    //writer.WriteLine("Welcome to Student TCP Server");
                   // writer.WriteLine("Please enter the student id");

                    while (true)
                    {
                        string id = reader.ReadLine();
                        SetText(id);
                       // writer.WriteLine("END");
                        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
                            break; // disconnect

                        //if (_data.ContainsKey(id))
                           // writer.WriteLine("Student's name: '{0}'", _data[id]);
                        else
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine("END");
                            // writer.WriteLine("Can't find name for student id '{0}'", id);
                        }
                            
                    }
                    stream.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    SetText("Error: " + ex);
                }

               // Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected: {0}",soc.RemoteEndPoint);
                soc.Close();
                currentconnect = currentconnect - 1;
                SetText("Numbers Connection " + currentconnect.ToString());
            }
        }
        private void SetText(string text)
        {
            if (this.rtbText.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText); // khởi tạo 1 delegate mới gọi đến SetText
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                this.AddMsg(text);

            }
        }
        private void SaveText(string text)
        {
            const string textFileName = "Log.txt";
            const int insertAtLineNumber = 0;

            List<string> fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(textFileName).ToList();
           // AddMsg(fileContent.Count.ToString());
            //fileContent.InsertRange(insertAtLineNumber, text);
            fileContent.Insert(insertAtLineNumber, text);
            File.WriteAllLines(textFileName, fileContent);
        }

        private void AddMsg(string msg)
        {

            rtbText.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + " : " + msg);
            SaveText(DateTime.Now + " : " + msg);
            if (rtbText.Items.Count >= 150)
            { rtbText.Items.RemoveAt(0); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I using MS SQL

Comment: Have a look at the [SqlConnection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Arduino card attached to PC 1  cannot be accessed from the PC 2.
You need to pass the Arduino data to the MSSQL Database. Then Retrieve the data in PC 2 by accessing it from PC 1. You can use this Reference for How to access Database over network

Comment: Thank you. So PC 1 has 2 network cards and 1 network card same LAN with PC 2, I think it is possible
In my case, it is not possible to directly update the data from Ardruino to MS SQL

Comment: So you need to get directly the data from the Arduino. Am I Right

Comment: Yes. As you see in my code, I writing data from to Log.txt ( receiving by card network 1 : 192.168.1.2). Now I want upload data directly to SQL by card network 2 (  110.110.1.2 )

Answer (score 0):

Up to now, when I returned this case I had a solution.
In PC1, there are 2 network cards, you just need to use the Network class to find the IP with the IP with IP in PC2
Instead of reading from the log file I was inspired directly from Arduino returned and transmitted to PC2

```
string hostname = Dns.GetHostName();
        System.Net.IPHostEntry ip = new IPHostEntry();
        ip = Dns.GetHostByName(hostname);

        foreach (IPAddress listip in ip.AddressList)
        {
             if (listip.ToString().StartsWith("110."))
            {
                ipMay = listip.ToString();
                macPairIp = GetMacByIP(ipMay);
                try
                {
                    //Do work here
                 }
                            catch (...)
                            {}
                                
            }
        }
```